# Deferred binding failed GWT using uibinder

Tags: gwt, web, uibinder, toolkit, deferred

Below are the total files used in project. It is giving these errors

```
[ERROR] [cricketscore] - Deferred binding failed for 'test.client.UserDashboard.MyUiBinder'; expect subsequent failures
```

and

```
[ERROR] [cricketscore] - Unable to load module entry point class test.client.DashBoard (see associated exception for details).
```

Please help me resolve the problem in it.

Cricketscore.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.0//EN"
  "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='cricketscore'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='test.client.DashBoard'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

Dashboard.java

```
package test.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class DashBoard implements EntryPoint{

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel.get().add(new UserDashboard());
    }
}
```

UserDashboard.ui.xml

```
<!-- UserDashboard.ui.xml -->

<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
    xmlns:my='urn:import:test.client' >

  <g:HTMLPanel>
    <my:CricketScores ui:field='scores' teamNames='AUS, SAF, WA, QLD, VIC'/>
  </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

CricketScores.java

```
package test.client;

import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiConstructor;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;


public class CricketScores extends Composite{

    public @UiConstructor CricketScores(String teamNames) {
          this(teamNames.split("[, ]+"));
        }

    public CricketScores(String... teamNames) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

UserDashboard.java

```
package test.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiFactory;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class UserDashboard extends Composite {
      interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, UserDashboard>{}
      private static final MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

      private final String[] teamNames;

      public UserDashboard(String... teamNames) {
        this.teamNames = teamNames;
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
      }

      @UiFactory CricketScores makeCricketScores() { 
        return new CricketScores(teamNames);
      }
    }
```

Comment: And the "...associated exception..." is where?

Comment: Exceptions are 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:406) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:5

Comment: Is that the *entire* exception? Try commenting out `this(teamNames.split("[, ]+"));` in the constructor.

Comment: Please run a compilation (rather than DevMode) for better exceptions, and update your question with the _full_ log.

Comment: Rebinding test.client.UserDashboard.MyUiBinder
         Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
            [ERROR] Class CricketScores has no appropriate setTeamNames() method: <my:CricketScores teamNames='AUS, SAF, WA, QLD, VIC' ui:field='scores'> (:8)
   [ERROR] Errors in 'test/client/UserDashboard.java'
      [ERROR] Line 13: Failed to resolve 'test.client.UserDashboard.MyUiBinder' via deferred binding
   [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
      [WARN] test.client.UserDashboard_MyUiBinderImpl

Comment: @thomas: upper comment is log after compilation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *conflicting* information in your code: a `@UiConstructor` and a `@UiFactory` (not conflicting actually, there's an order of precedence, but it can be confusing to the developer, i.e. you).

UiBinder will prefer the `@UiFactory` over the `@UiConstructor`, and your factory has no argument, so the `teamNames` attribute from your XML is tentatively mapped to a `setTeamNames` setter, which doesn't exist, hence the *“Class CricketScores has no appropriate setTeamNames() method”* error.

The problem is conceptual in your code: your `UserDashboard` is constructed with a list of team names that it passes to the `CricketScores` widget, so that widget shouldn't have a `teamNames` attribute in the XML.

Comment: thanx man .... do you know any site for uifactory and uiconstructor except google-developers site.... they have given very limited about these concepts

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error and uiField(provided=true) was getting null but it got resolved when I created object of respective component in constructor